# PostgreSQL - 'could not truncate file "global/21607": permission denied'

Tags: postgresql, perl

So I inherited a Windows system that runs a perl script that connects to a local PostgreSQL database (also on running on this Windows Server). It moves data from one table to another.

I got the following error:

```
could not truncate file "global/21607": permission denied
```

Is it possible to find which table corresponds to "global/21607"?

Comment: Found this, might help... https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-filename-to-table/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a recent version of PostgreSQL, you could try:

```
SELECT pg_filenode_relation(
          (SELECT oid FROM pg_tablespace WHERE spcname = 'pg_global'),
          21607
       );
```

Could it be that there is an anti-virus program running that locks the file?

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code above and got the following :pg_filenode_relation
----------------------

(1 row)

Comment: I made a mistake with the number - does it return anything with 21607?

Comment: I re-ran again but it comes back with :pg_filenode_relation ---------------------- (1 row) –

Comment: Well, then no relation corresponds to this filenode.